# function imagecreatetruecolor() is not working in my server

Tags: php, joomla1.5, fatal-error

In my website's cpanel it shows that

> Apache version : 2.0.63 PHP version : 5.2.9 MySQL version :
>   5.0.92-community Operating system : linux

I currently installed a joomla website inside the server. I am using a module named "negetics PSS" as my homepage banner.

Here is the working model of the banner :
http://extensions.negetics.de/negetics-Presentation-Slider-Slim/demo-1.html

as you can see in the demo, the 6 handles of that slider is generated using php **imagecreatetruecolor** function. Now my problem is that, while i am using this module in my server, the module is generating error in its error log that :

> [24-Oct-2011 02:32:27] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function
>   imagecreatetruecolor() in.....

as a result you can imagine, the handles are not generating.
How do i fix this..?
please Help me.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have GD > 2.0.1 installed? check with phpinfo()

Comment: No. I don't have GD installed. Checked with phpinfo(). Now what should i do.?

Comment: Well...install it? :) If you are not allowed by your host, drop them a line and have it done for you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Install Gd library. follow the below link. [GD library instalation](http://php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php)